# If a computer is connected to a proxy, will all outgoing traffic go through that proxy?

Tags: php, proxy

My computer is connected to a local proxy. I want to know whether the outgoing script traffic from my computer goes through that proxy. If it is true  how can I know? I'm using PHP scripts.

Comment: it is going to depend on the kind of proxy you are using and how your computer is configured to connect to it. Packet captures are how you can know where your traffic is heading.

Comment: it is connected to tor proxy @schroeder

Comment: I don't mean where the proxy sends the traffic, I mean what does the proxy expect to handle? All network traffic? Just traffic from a specific browser?

Comment: all network traffic. I'm using windows and I set the proxy in windows settings, to 127.0.0.1:9050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your computer is connected to a local proxy this does not mean that all traffic is passing through this proxy. Only the applications which are aware of the proxy will use it. All other application will not use the proxy which means that they either have no connectivity at all (if the proxy is the only connectivity) or that they bypass the proxy and connect directly to the target.

Applications which are aware of the system wide proxy setting you have configured are usually the browsers (although Firefox and Chrome can have separate configurations too) but usually not some PHP programs you execute on the system.

Comment: how can I make the PHP programs I execute ,to be aware of the system wide proxy settings

Comment: @theModerator713: I doubt that there is a general way for PHP to use the system proxy. But depending on the library you use within PHP you can set the proxy within the PHP code, like described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy. But that's a programming question already and off-topic here.